# Retrieve Access Token from IdentityServer

Tags: token, identityserver4

I need to get hold of the access token in the Login action of my AccountController of IdentityServer web app.

I need this access token in this action method so that I can log some audit related information to a table in the database.

I am not able to find out how I can get hold of this access token.

I have the following:

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient("https://www.example.com/Identity/connect/token", "my.web", new Secret("secret".Sha256()).ToString());

var response = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync("code", "https://www.example.com/myweb/callback.html");
var token = response.AccessToken;
```

The value for the token is always coming as NULL. I am not sure what value I should pass for the "code". From where can I retrieve this value.

Kindly share some detailed example of how I can retrieve the access token.

Comment: You can test the response. `if (tokenResponse.IsError) Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);`

Comment: The error has unauthorized_client mentioned. I have checked the configuration and I dont think that there is an issue there. However, as I mentioned in my post, I am not sure what value needs to be passed to "code" in the RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync call. 

Kindly suggest